# Why use `bash -c` in supervisor instead of calling script directly?

Tags: linux, bash, supervisord

I'm beginning to use `supervisord` to control services in my server. I'm not a pro user of linux but can get with it quite well and get it running.

Just out of curiosity, I've noticed that most commands in supervisord seem to be called like:

```
[program:install]
command=bash -c "/src/etc/install.sh"
```

I've read bash's man, and know that `-c` should be used to insert variables passed after the string.

So what's the point in using `bash -c` in supervisor (or any other place) instead of calling the script directly (like example below), considering that no variables where passed/used?

```
[program:install]
command=/src/etc/install.sh
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shell features such as pathname expansion (`*`, `?`), command lists (`;`, `&&`, `||`), redirection (`<`, `>`, `|`,) are not implemented by supervisord that only splits the command into an array of argument strings.

The `bash -c` may be just a help for novice user who might be tempted to use such features in the command. For example it avoids the surprise that

```
command=echo foo > /tmp/bar
```

outputs `foo > /tmp/bar` instead of writing `foo` to `/tmp/bar`.

`-c` has little to do with variables. Any additional arguments to the bash would only be available as script arguments `$0`, `$1`, etc. in the command, but that feature has seldom any use. For example `bash -c 'echo $0 $0' foo` outputs `foo foo`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very pragmatic answer, and that'll probably save me a lot of time. I, as a novice user, would make this mistake (and never think about `bash -c` as a solution!).

Answer (score 7):

It is explained [in the documentation](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment):

> No shell is executed by supervisord when it runs a subprocess, so environment variables such as USER, PATH, HOME, SHELL, LOGNAME, etc. are not changed from their defaults or otherwise reassigned. This is particularly important to note when you are running a program from a supervisord run as root with a user= stanza in the configuration.

To get around this issue `bash -c` may be used.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your answer but I think the other one was a more plausible scenario (while yours is not incorrect to me, I still need to choose one right answer..). Besides that, i'm also helping the new user with fewer points.

Comment: Bash does not change any of the listed environment variables. It does set SHELL, if it is not set when it is started, but leaves it to old value if it is set. So having `bash -c ""` in command does not fix these variables. The document tells to use the `environment=` configuration option to set them properly.